# fragment recyclerview is giving this error E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I,ve tried everything and nothing is working... Any solution please. if i use listview it works perfectly but on recycler view i'm getting an error.

the code is below

home fragment

```
    recyclerViewOne = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewOne);
    collectionReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("Trending songs");
    recyclerViewOne.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewOne.setLayoutManager(new 
    LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
    mUpload = new ArrayList<>();
    gridViewHolder = new GridViewHolder(getActivity(), mUpload, new 
    GridViewHolder.ItemClickListeners() {
        @Override
        public void onClicke(GridModel model, int post) {
            ((DashboardActivity) getActivity()).method();
            ((DashboardActivity) getActivity()).playO(post);

        }
    });
    recyclerViewOne.setAdapter(gridViewHolder);
```

i need some help please

Comment: Please share GridViewHolder class

Comment: There is no `e` at `onClick`

Answer (score 0):

According to the naming, you are trying the set a ViewHolder as an adapter to the recycler. If that is the case, then you should implement it the correct way: a custom Adapter that extends RecyclerView.Adapter and that add that adapter to the recycler view

Answer (score 0):

this is the GridViewHolder

public class GridViewHolder extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GridViewHolder.SongsAdapterViewHolder> {

```
Context context;
List<GridModel> gridModels;
private ItemClickListeners listeners;
private int selected;

@NonNull
@Override
public SongsAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent,false);

    return new SongsAdapterViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SongsAdapterViewHolder holder, int position) {

    GridModel gridModel = gridModels.get(position);
    holder.mDesc.setText(gridModel.getmDesc());
    holder.mTitle.setText(gridModel.getmTitle());
    String duration = Utility.convertion(Long.parseLong(gridModel.getDuration()));
    Glide.with(context).load(gridModel.imageurl).into(holder.imageurl);
    holder.bind(gridModel, listeners);
}

public GridViewHolder(Context context, List<GridModel> gridModels, ItemClickListeners listeners) {
    this.context = context;
    this.gridModels = gridModels;
    this.listeners = listeners;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return gridModels.size();
}
public class SongsAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView mTitle, mDesc;
    ImageView imageurl;

    public SongsAdapterViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gridTitle);
        mDesc= itemView.findViewById(R.id.gridMusician);
        imageurl  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gridImageView);
    }

    public void bind(final GridModel gridModel, final ItemClickListeners listeners) {
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listeners.onClicke(gridModel, getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
    }
}

public interface ItemClickListeners {
    void onClicke(GridModel model, int post);
}

public int getSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(int selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}
```

}